# Como adicionar item em array através de um foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, array, arquivo

Estou fazendo uma verificação em um diretório onde listo todos os itens com uma extensão específica.

E preciso adicionar os itens em um *array* através de um `foreach`.

Segue parte do código que já tentei.

```
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(_caminhoEmail);
 FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.ost");
 string[] pasta = new string[] { };
 foreach (FileInfo item in rgFiles)
 {
     pasta = new string[] { item.FullName};
 }
 return pasta;
```

Mas com esse código ele sempre sobrescreve pegando somente o último valor do *array* em `rgFiles[]`.

Como faço para adicionar os itens no `Array pasta` e retorná-lo no final?

Comment: `FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.ost");` aqui ele já te traz um array de informação, não pode usar essa?

Comment: O erro esta aqui: `pasta = new string[] { item.FullName };`. Você cria uma nova instancia sobrepondo o anterior. Fazer com `foreach` dá, mas não é o mais acertado para o que você precisa, seria muito código desnecessário. Recomendo avaliar o comentário e a resposta   do @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema seja a atribuição. Precisa ser *array* mesmo? Acho que seria melhor fazer com um `for`.

```
 var di = new DirectoryInfo(_caminhoEmail);
 FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.ost");
 var pasta = new string[regFiles.Length];
 for (var i = 0; i < rgFiles.Length; i++) pasta[i] = rgFiles[i].FullName;
 return pasta;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/ChangeItems.cs).

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente. E exatamente como eu queria. Valeu !!!

Answer (score 4):

Pode utilizar [***Linq***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx), não precisando nesse caso em especifico utilizar uma *estrutura de repetição*.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(_caminhoEmail);
FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.ost");
return rgFiles.Select(e => e.FullName).ToList();
```